# Redirecting a Url in codeIgniter to a root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a folder structure like this in Code igniter : -

```
- www
    - CI
      - application
        - config
          - config.php
      - adminfolder
      - system
      - css
      - jss
```

And now i want to redirect the Url when the user goes  to the controller : formhandler and action: login  of url, `http://localhost/CI/formhandler/login`     to this : `http://localhost/CI/adminfolder` How to do this ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: `redirect(base_url('adminfolder'));`

Comment: Let me check that ,thanks

Comment: You might want to look into the `.htaccess` for `adminfolder` because it might have been blocked for access.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using URL Helper of CodeIgniter.

This helper library should br loaded using the following code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

To redirect you just need to call function as follow. Put this code inside your login method.

```
redirect('http://localhost/CI/adminfolder');
```

Reference code: http://dwij.co.in/redirect-to-url-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

assuming your base url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/CI/";
```

it's simply to do:

```
redirect(site_url('adminfolder'),'',301/*here your redirect http code*/);
```

and be sure the folder is accessible via browser

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fix it by updating my .htaccess file with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I found it from https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html